# Objective C get MongoDB ObjectID from .Net API as string and vice versa

Tags: objective-c, mongodb, asp.net-web-api, objectid

I have to consume .Net API which return and use MongoDB ObjectId as result and parameter

For example, server return

```
    _id": {
            "Timestamp": 1478679428,
            "Machine": 1031587,
            "Pid": 9124,
            "Increment": 2344035,
            "CreationTime": "/Date(1478679428000)/"
        }
```

In form of `NSDictionary` for ObjectID value `ObjectId("5822db840fbda323a423c463")`

My question is: How can I convert above `NSDictionary` _id to string value `5822db840fbda323a423c463` in Objective C ?

And vice versa, convert `NSString` `5822db840fbda323a423c463` to `NSDictionary` for sending as api parameter ?

Note that: **I can't change api**, only consume it

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post my work result as answer, hope it help others in the future

For serializing `NSDictionary` from API result to `NSString`

```
- (NSString *)NSStringFromNSDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    long Timestamp = [[dict objectForKey:@"Timestamp"] longValue];
    long Machine = [[dict objectForKey:@"Machine"] longValue];
    long Pid = [[dict objectForKey:@"Pid"] longValue];
    long Increment = [[dict objectForKey:@"Increment"] longValue];

    NSString *oid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08lx%06lx%04lx%06lx", Timestamp, Machine, Pid, Increment];

    return oid;
}
```

For serializing `NSString` back to .Net Mongo ObjectId in form of `NSDictionary`

```
- (NSDictionary *)NSStringFromNSDictionary:(NSString *)oid
{
    long Timestamp = strtol([[oid substringToIndex:8] UTF8String], NULL, 16);
    long Machine = strtol([[oid substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8,6)] UTF8String], NULL, 16);
    long Pid = strtol([[oid substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(14,4)] UTF8String], NULL, 16);
    long Increment = strtol([[oid substringFromIndex:18] UTF8String], NULL, 16);


    NSDictionary * dict = @{@"Timestamp": [NSNumber numberWithLong:Timestamp]
                        ,@"Machine": [NSNumber numberWithLong:Machine]
                        ,@"Pid": [NSNumber numberWithLong:Pid]
                        ,@"Increment": [NSNumber numberWithLong:Increment]
                        ,@"CreationTime": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%ld)/",Timestamp*1000]
                        };

    return dict;
}
```